# VBA execute code in string

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to execute vba code that is inside a string WITHOUT writting the code in a temp file.

For exemple :

```
Dim code As String
code = "n = 0 : e_i_e = 0 : For e_i_e = 0 To 100 : n+=1 : Next"
```

I have tried Eval, Evaluate, Run, executeGlobal and adding a new module with

```
Set VBComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
    VBComp.Name = "NewModule"
 Set VBCodeMod = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("NewModule").CodeModule
    With VBCodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, _
        "Sub MyNewProcedure()" & Chr(13) & _
        code & Chr(13) & _
        "End Sub"
    End With
    Application.Run "MyNewProcedure"
```

but all of these are returning errors ='(.

Thank you !

Comment: What errors, where?

Comment: Your code is c# addition, it needs to be `n=n+1`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav or VB.NET

Comment: @BruceWayne OP cannot break in the generated procedure, that makes it much harder to debug than normal code. That said, OP should try to execute their code string in a normally-compiled procedure before trying to execute ad-hoc strings. The error would be trivially revealed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a module and populate it with a sub from a string.  In fact one of the way developers place their vba code into a repository is to do just that: extract the code from modules as strings and then read them back in from whatever version control software they're using.

Here's a full example to do what you're looking to do (assuming you want your sub in a new separate module):

```
Sub make_module_sub_and_run():
    Dim strMacro As String
    Dim myModule As VBComponent

    Set myModule = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
    strMacro = "Public Sub exampleSub()" & vbCrLf & _
               "  n=0" & vbCrLf & _
               "  For e_i_e = 0 to 100:" & vbCrLf & _
               "    n=n+1" & vbCrLf & _
               "  Next" & vbCrLf & _
               "  MsgBox(""Hello World. Oh and n="" & n)" & vbCrLf & _
               "End Sub"

    myModule.CodeModule.AddFromString strMacro
    Application.Run myModule.Name & ".exampleSub"

End Sub
```

Note that what should happen as you type "vbext_ct_StdModule" is that excel intellisense will note that this is missing and will ask whether you want to load it in - which you, of course, do.

Also note that I've deliberately prefixed the sub with the module name when running it - otherwise if you were to run it repeatedly you'll create new modules with a sub of the same name and excel wouldn't know which one to run.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot break in code that's been generated after you've compiled your project, so you need to make sure you build that dynamic module with valid, compilable code.

You know *before you hit that F5 button* that your code is going to look like this:

```
Sub MyNewProcedure()
    n = 0 : e_i_e = 0 : For e_i_e = 0 To 100 : n+=1 : Next
End Sub
```

Why not just take that snippet and paste it somewhere and see what the VBE complains about?

[image: Compile error: syntax error]

Wow. See, this is why cramming half a dozen instructions on the same line of code is a bad idea - if it was one instruction per line you wouldn't be wondering which one is broken.

[As was already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42232074/1188513), `n += 1` is not VBA syntax (it's not specifically C# syntax either); incrementing a value in VBA needs to access the current value, so `n = n + 1`.

It's not clear where `n` and `e_i_e` are coming from. If both are locals, then your procedure accomplishes essentially nothing. If `n` is declared outside `MyNewProcedure`, then you should consider passing it as a `ByRef` parameter, or better, leaving it out completely and making a `Function` with the result of which the calling code assigns `n` to.

```
Sub MyNewProcedure(ByRef n As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 100
        n = i
    Next
End Sub
```

Which boils down to:

```
Function MyNewFunction() As Long
    MyNewFunction = 100
End Function
```

Which makes me wonder what the heck you're trying to accomplish.

If there is a bug in your generated code, you're going to have to debug it in a string, because the VBE's debugger won't let you break on generated code - this means it's crucially important that you generate code in a readable and maintainable way. There's currently nowhere in your code where you have the actual full generated code in a clear string - it's concatenated inline inside the `InsertLines` call.

Consider:

```
Dim code As String
code = "'Option Explicit" & vbNewLine & _
       "Public Sub MyNewProcedure()" & vbNewLine & _
       "    n = 0" & vbNewLine & _
       "    e_i_e = 0" & vbNewLine & _
       "    For e_i_e = 0 To 100" & vbNewLine & _
       "        n = n + 1 ' fixed from n += 1" & vbNewLine & _
       "    Next" & vbNewLine & _
       "End Sub" & vbNewLine
'...
'Debug.Print code
.InsertLines LineNum, code
```

It's much easier to get the full code back while debugging, and much easier to review and fix as well. Note that there's a limit to how many line continuations you can chain though.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is c# addition, it needs to be `n=n+1`