# ExecuteGlobal not working in excel macro when trying to use external vbscript vbs file

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am trying to use an external vbs file in my excel macro.
The vbs file contains classes and methods which I want to use.

But ExecuteGlobal not working. I have tried to search a lot but all the posts are nearly five years old leaving few.
There is no error in vbs file and tried it with another text file but it is showing compile time error at same place only
Can any one help me.

[image]

Comment: `ExecuteGlobal` does not exist in VBA.

Comment: VBS can mostly be pasted into VBA.

Comment: @Mark good luck. I would say in most cases you would need at least to adjust the code. What you say may be true for some statements but not for an entire code.

Comment: Anything not wrapped in a class is able to be pasted into VBA. That was a design goal of VBScript. When VBA was released MS promoted a coding style the exact same as VBScript. People whinged about performance and MS changed their tune.

Comment: @Mark I mean if you have a VBScript that interacts with an Excel wonkbook/sheet already you would need to re-write that part, as it could not interact with `ThisWorkbook` in your Excel file then. Also it would be recommended to use typed variables in VBA (which VBS does not support). So even if a code change is only necessary in the first case a review is highly recommended. • Furthermore the OP said the VBS uses classes so that would not be able to run with just pasting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA execute code in string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42231887)

Answer (score 2):

Note that you cannot include VBS in VBA and `ExecuteGlobal` does not exist in VBA.

So either you run the VBS as an external script:

```
Shell "wscript c:\null\a.vbs", vbNormalFocus
```

or you need to re-write the VBScript classes in VBA. Most of the VBA code would not need too much adjustments, but on the other hand a simple copy/paste would not work neither.